# Run Applescript on selected text and store it on clipboard

Tags: applescript, automator

I'm looking for a solution to be able to select a text on an app(Figma) and then reverse it then store reverse version to the clipboard.
I used [BetterTouchBar](https://folivora.ai) app for saving selected text but I can't do anything with it.
[image]

How can I do that with or without BetterTouchbar App.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Create an **Automator** *Quick Action*<sup>1</sup>, setting **Workflow receives current text in any application** and add a **Run AppleScript** *action*, adding the following line of *example* **AppleScript** *code* where is says: **(* Your script goes here *)**

```
set the clipboard to the (reverse of characters of item 1 of input) as text
```

Save the *Quick Action* as e.g.: **Reverse Selected Text To Clipboard**

It's now available from the **Services** menu in any application, e.g. **TextEdit** > **Services**, or the **Services** menu on the **Context** menu (right-click menu).

You can also assign a keyboard shortcut in: **System Preferences** > **Keyboard** > **Shortcuts** > **Services**

---

<sup>1</sup> In versions of **macOS** prior to **Mojave** a **Quick Action** is called a **Service**.

---

Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and does not contain any error handling as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the used to add any error handling as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1).